# EditText focus not going after finishing activity

Tags: android

In my form activity, I've 3 fields. After confirming the form to the server it finishes and go to the previous activity. But the problem , After finish the keyboard is still pop up and the previous activity has no input field. 
Here is the layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <sslwireless.com.easycorporate.Fonts.LoraBold
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:text="@string/change_password_title"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/oldPassword"
                android:background="@drawable/super_white_style"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="@string/hints_old_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/newPassword"
                android:background="@drawable/super_white_style"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="@string/hints_new_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/confirmPassword"
                android:background="@drawable/super_white_style"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="@string/hints_confirm_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/changePassword"
                android:text="@string/change_password"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:background="@drawable/primary_dark_color_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here what actually happening.

[image]

i also set the `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` for both activity in the manifest file. is there any way I can remove focus after go back to the previous activity ?

Comment: so you want to hide your soft keyboard at certain point. right ? which is not happening automatically .

Comment: Yes something like that .

Comment: Why i'm getting down vote ?

Comment: when you open your profile Activity , do the keyboard stays there indefenitely . or it goes away after some time ?

Comment: In my Profile Activity there are no EditText. So there is no chance to to show the keyboard .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may force IME to close (before you `finish()` your activity):

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    IBinder windowToken = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getWindowToken();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `onStop()` of the finishing `Activity`, disable all the `EditText` fields like this in order to make the soft keyboard disappear:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.confirmPassword);
et.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

call below code for close keybord , call when click on button

```
InputMethodManager imk = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imk.isActive()){
            imk.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0); // hide key board
        }
```

Comment: I already told that there are no `edittext` in the previous activity .

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that actually fixed an identical bug today.

```
@Override
public void closeKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            //Log.d("RKZ", "isKeyboardShown("+((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0)+") = "+isKeyboardShown(((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0)));
    if(view != null && Util.isSoftKeyboardShown(imm, view)) {
        Util.hideKeyboard(ActivityASG.this, view);
    }
}
```

And in your `CHANGE PIN` Button's `onClick()` just call it like this:

```
            //close keyboard
            callback.closeKeyboard(noteInput);
            callback.closeKeyboard(mailInput);
            //callback.closeKeyboard(yourCHANGE_PINview);
```